# Make phone ring through webserver using Asterisk

Tags: php, asterisk

What is the easiest way? And how can it be implemented?

I thought to something like:

1. I request a page to the webserver
2. Php sends to asterisk a number to dial (php and asterisk are running in the same machine)
3. Asterisk calls the phone

or

1. A php sip client registers to remote asterisk server
2. Php sip client sends to asterik the number to dial
3. Phone rings

i don't care if i can hear something, it's enough that it rings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Call File**

The easiest way is to generate a Call File.
Asterisk has the feature to initiate Calls through a spool directory.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Call+Files

Hints and Notes:

- you have to create the call file in a seperate directory
  and move it (do not use copy, because asterisk parses the file immediately, but move is safe) into the spool directory.
- The call file must be owned by the user asterisk runs as
- asterisk (utime() on the file ) checks the modification timestamp, and schedules the call on it, if the modified timestamp is in the future

**AMI - the Asterisk Manager Interface**

It is also possible to [initiate a Call over a Script (AMI)](http://etel.wiki.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Initiating_a_call_from_a_script_%28AMI%29).
You have to set up a login (ie. username, password) in manager.conf.
Test the AMI with Telnet at the asterisk server ip at port 5038:

```
Action: Login
Username: username
Secret: password

Action: Originate
Channel: SIP/123
Context: default
Exten: 012345678
Priority: 1
Callerid: AMICall

Action: Logoff
```

You could also use PHP-AMI (comes with [PHP-AGI](http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/) ) to dial out.

Secutity Note of [manager.conf](http://doxygen.asterisk.org/trunk/Config_ami.html):

```
 ---------------------------- SECURITY NOTE -------------------------------
; Note that you should not enable the AMI on a public IP address. If needed,
; block this TCP port with iptables (or another FW software) and reach it
; with IPsec, SSH, or SSL vpn tunnel.  You can also make the manager
; interface available over http/https if Asterisk's http server is enabled in
; http.conf and if both "enabled" and "webenabled" are set to yes in
; this file.  Both default to no.  httptimeout provides the maximum
; timeout in seconds before a web based session is discarded.  The
; default is 60 seconds.
;
```

**AJAM - the asynchronous Javascript Asterisk Manager**

AJAM is a Webserver which you could enable and use to communicate to the Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI) over http.

Comment: maybe the last 2 are more insecure... is it?
Anyway i'm going to try the first.
Do i need to do chown to these files? Asterisk is running as root

Comment: i didn't use ajam. But you can use AMI and block the Managerinterfaceport (for extern) at your firewall.

Comment: When the webserver can write into the spooldir and asterisk can read those files, you don't need to chown.

Comment: Channel: SIP/NUMBERTODIAL
Callerid: Asterisk
Context: my-ivr
Extension: s
worked for me, is it alright?

Comment: Yes, if SIP/NUMBERTODIAL is a "local" SIP Extension and that extension gets in the [my-ivr] Context in the Dialplan at s,1.

Comment: there is a problem, i've php running with cgi and as user, and when i use exec() to move the file nothing happens. Maybe a problem with permissions?

Comment: i did chmod 777 /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/ and worked, is it insecure?

Comment: can't answer yes or no, i would recommend to install http://www.fail2ban.org/ (for more asterisk and server security).