# Javascript AMI for firing commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, asterisk, socket.io

I have Asterisk server is running on my LAN, Now I want to use Javascript to perform the socket connection to that running application via AMI (Asterisk Manager Interface).

Can any one suggest me Javascript client for AMI to fire commands to Asterisk server for login , originating call and other events.

For command reference :
[Make phone ring through webserver using Asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041425/make-phone-ring-through-webserver-using-asterisk)

Edit 1: thanks for your answer. I have tried NodeJS-AsteriskManger but got error while running index.js as

```
C:\wamp\www\ASTERISK\github\node-asterisk-master\node-asterisk-master\asterisk.j
s:145
 idCaller = headers.uniqueid, idCallee = self.participants[idCaller]['with'],
                                                                    ^
    C:\wamp\www\ASTERISK\github\NodeJS-AsteriskManager-master\NodeJS-AsteriskManager
    -master\index.js:16
                true); // This parameter determines whether events are emited.
                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these Node.js modules to communicate with asterisk server -

https://github.com/phidelta/NodeJS-AsteriskManager
https://github.com/holidayextras/node-asterisk-ami
https://github.com/asterisk/node-ari-client (by Digium/Asterisk)

Comment: Vinayr, thanks for your response, I have tried https://github.com/phidelta/NodeJS-AsteriskManager but it gives me error which has been added to question for your information. So, whats the issue here, cay you please provide me suggestion or let me know am I doing something wrong.

Comment: I guess new require is missing `)`

Comment: did you do like this `true));` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var ami = new require('asterisk-manager')('port','host','username','password',true);
```